# how to add additional images to a product in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Can anyone please let me know how to add additional images to a product. I already have an image with Small Image, Base Image, Thumbnail radio boxes selected and I want to upload another or additional image for that product without selecting all the 3 radio buttons. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the images tab you just need to browse for the image who wish to add and click the Upload files button.  For the additional image you do not have to select any of the radio buttons.

[image]

If that is not the issue we would need more detail.

Maybe the issue is with the template file on the product view page?  Is this were you expect to see the additional image.  Turn on template path hints to see what template file is being called, probably template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml, there maybe an error in your code here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can add images from backend and can see on the frontend for 1 product but here i want to upload images for 1600 products. Is there anyway that I can upload images for 1600 products?? Thanks

Comment: @Pradeep oh, you can with the [Magmi Mass Importer tool](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).  With it, if you put the image files in the in the /media/import directory and reference the image file names in a csv file seperated with a `;`, Magmi can import them all for you.

Comment: is there any other way apart from Magmi? i mean via script or csv import..Thanks

Comment: @Pradeep, not that I'm aware of, it's one of the shortcomings of Magento which magmi was developed for.  Many people think it should be added to the magento core